# How to efficiently allocate memory for big raster file in lidR v2.2.4?

Tags: lidr

I am intended to find trees from a CHM created in agisoft with total raster size of 1.2GB with this following code:

```r
library(lidR)
library(future)

# set to use 8 cores with future
plan(multisession, workers=8L)

mainDir <- "E:/02.CHM/01.Agisoft_Analysis/South"
inDir <- "4_ground_classified"
outDir1 <- "5_trees"
rasterfile <- "CHM_0.1_South.tif"
treefile = "tree_south.csv"

dir.create(file.path(mainDir, outDir1), showWarnings = TRUE)  

chm <- raster(file.path(mainDir, inDir, rasterfile))
ttops <- tree_detection(chm, lmf(ws=5, hmin=1.37, shape=c("circular") ))
```

When I was processing the raster with `tree_detection()` function in `lidR v2.2.4`, it failed with this message:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 647.2 Mb.
```

I tweaked by creating a tiled raster with this command

```
chm <- raster(file.path(mainDir, outDir1, "CHM_0.1_South.vrt")
ttops <- tree_detection(chm, lmf(ws=5, hmin=1.37, shape=c("circular") ))
```

But the same error message still appears.

The second tweak was by using `memory.allocation()` trick, but that also didn't work.

As for your information, my RAM size is 16GB.

I found [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-LAScatalog-class.html) to work on parallel computation for las files, but I can't find a way to do parallel computation on VRT .tif file.

Do you have any suggestion on how to do parallel processing computation for tiled .tif raster?
Given the fact that R can't allocate enough memory if I work in one big .tif raster file.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange. Please edit your question to include a reproducible code as well as all relevant information about your objects loaded in memory and so on.

Comment: I can't see any question here. The problem seems clear: R cannot allocate enough memory. You need to work with smaller pieces of your original rasters

Comment: Hi @JRR,

Thanks for your reply.

I have created smaller raster tiles in QGIS and loaded the VRT file with the same command.
`raster("E:/02.CHM/01.Agisoft_Analysis/South/5_trees/CHM_0.1_South.vrt")`
And the same message still appears.

Based on your suggestion, it is better to apply `tree_detection()` for every smaller piece of raster.
If it is assumed that the tiles were cut in the middle of local maxima of the trees.
Will buffer improves the result?
Or can I apply [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-LAS-class.html) for raster?

Comment: Edit your question to include what you did with the VRT. And include a question.